# Escape wildcard, *, in sp_addsrvrolemember

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to escape a wildcard * in the below stored procedure?

`exec sp_addsrvrolemember '*Everyone-Group', 'sysadmin'`

I need the script to identify * but not as a wildcard, but rather as an asterisk.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this a `like` pattern?

Comment: I don't recall seeing anywhere that '`*`' is considered a wildcard in SQL. What you normally have (and I guess this is what Gordon refers to) is to use wildcard in queries where you use a `like` patter, something like `... where Username like '%ABC%'` (i.e. where the username contains the letters `ABD`). Here' the `%` serves as a wildcard.

Comment: Why are you using `sp_addsrvrolemember`? it's been deprecated for years (note the huge blue box in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addsrvrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). Use `ALTER SERVER ROLE`. Specifically it'll be `ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [*Everyone-Group];`

Comment: @Larnu I did not know it was deprecated, I was using it because I do not know any SQL and it worked with my PowerShell script when adding individual domain accounts but got stuck when I came across a user group with the * character in it. But having read the article, I will make modifications accordingly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No. no, I literally just have this one line where I specify exactly the account that I need added to the Logins in SQL and assign sysadmin permission

Comment: @FDavidov I read on w3School * is one of the wildcards, for example SELECT * FROM Table 1, means the * will select ALL from Table 1. That is my minimal understanding of it

Comment: @Larnu I have used the ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [*Everyone-Group]; however ran into an error: "Cannot add the server principal '*Everyone-Group', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." Thing is, I am sysadmin on the SQL server and admin on the server itself. I will keep investigating but just FYI if you have seen this before

Comment: That is the *only* place `*` means "everything", @JohnDoe . I may be wrong, but had you tried the code you have I expect it would have worked anyway.

Comment: @Larnu sorry, pressed enter by accident, see the edited above.

Comment: *"Cannot add the server principal '*Everyone-Group', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."* That error cannot be more clear. There is no `LOGIN` with the name `*Everyone-Group` on your instance.

Comment: @Larnu That is correct, the login is not there because I have not added it yet, I am trying to do that with the original code in my first post, I assumed the update script would do that for me but then realised ALTER only modifies what's already there correct? So how do I add a login and escape the * character?

Comment: What do you mean escape the `*` character? You can't escape it, it doesn't need it. The only character that needs escaping is `]` when using brackets to delimit identify

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP appears to think that `*` is a wildcard character, like `%` is in a `LIKE` expression. The only place `*` operators as a "wildcard" is when it is used to replace a column's name in a `SELECT` (I.e. `SELECT *` means return all columns, and `SELECT MT.*, OT.ID` would mean all the columns. From the object aliased `MT`). It appears they have simply misread something, as `*` is not a wildcard.

Comment: @JohnDoe, the usage of the `*` must not be considered as a wildcard in `SELECT *…`. This is the standard syntax in SQL saying _All columns in the table_. Now, SQL knows two wildcards: `_ABC` which is interpreted as _any character_ (meaning one and only one character) _before `ABC`_, and `%ABC` which means _zero or more characters before `ABC`_.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I reached out to a SQL expert to educate me and here is what I needed:

```
CREATE LOGIN [_Everyone-Group] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master] 
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [_Everyone-Group]
```

As for my misunderstandings:

- The * is only considered a wildcard in MS Access, not SQL like it was mentioned in this post
- The line of code "ALTER SERVER ROLE" assumes the login is already existing in the master database, I had thought it would look for it and add it in (because of ADD MEMBER) and then also apply 'sysadmin' permissions.
- I did not know the _ was needed instead of * in the brace.